# How can you put logo on your CrystalReport within the Header?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

Is there a way in CrystalReport that you can put a logo on your header? If so,  are there any examples how that works?

Comment: Did you mean dynamic logo from database or just want to set a logo from folder manually?

Comment: Your logo is same in all scenarios? or need to change it programmatically?

Comment: logo from folder manually mate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Crystal Reports : Insert an image in the Report Header section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397893/crystal-reports-insert-an-image-in-the-report-header-section)

Comment: @B-rian thanks mate so much, i met my goal for this top.